# Is it common to have 2 (or even more) models in MVC?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, model, uml

Is it common to have 2 (or even more) models in MVC app?
Because I am working on app for displaying weather and I need model for managing weather data, and second model for managing settings (like show results immediately during typing in searchbar or only on button press)...
Should I use only one model (combine both my model into one), or it is OK in software design to have multiple models?
Of course the only reason for separated models in my program is to have clear code...
Tahnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already a couple of useful answers here.  For the records, a more formal one, according to [the inventor of MVC](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/%7Etrygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html):

- An application has only one controller, because it's the link between the application and the user input.
- An application may have several views.
- An application may use several models: so no problem for having two separate models each handling a [separate concern](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/).
- Moreover a model may be used by several applications.

Of course, one controler/view/model does not mean one class:  several classes may work together to fulfil the role.   This is why the MVC is often presented in a simplified version with one model: in the end, from an OOP perspective, it does not matter if the many classes that compose the model belong to one or more abstract models.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned two requirements : Managing Weather Data and Managing Settings.
Even by going through the literal meaning of these two, you would require different view/controller/Model. Managing these two in single View/Controller/Model will really be complicated and prone to errors.

Even for Individual requirement of Weather Data or Managing Settings, if you find that code looks better with multiple Models then definitely you should add multiple models. Conceptually it is not forbidden or something in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case you better use 2 models. And it is not forbidden in MVC as someone said.
Anything that makes the code clearer is good.

Comment: please post this type of short answers inside comment

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the approach you are using.
You can achieve the functionality somehow but its always better to follow the standards.

Just for clarification,
if you are using ajax to fetch the data and binding it using Jquery or any client side library or framework, then you may use the separate models and event two separate ajax methods.

if you are using the strongly typed C# ViewModel declaring it at the beginning of the CSHtml page and utilizing the razor syntax, then you should use Common Model combining the two separate ones.